# Wordpress posts not displaying despite existing in the database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My site was hacked recently and I believe this issue came up after a fresh install of wordpress and re-upload of the theme along with it's plugins

The posts are showing up on http://medicalais.com/blog/ if you click on them individual however a completely blank page is rendered. The posts exist along with their category relationships. They are not showing up even in the posts dashboard. I cannot edit them or view them. It does say 26 posts exist and 26 posts are published but I cannot select any of them.

I've done everything to debug this issue.

I ran the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "post" AND post_status = "publish"
```

I noticed all the articles are in the database. So, I repaired the table anyways but the issue persists.

I also reset the plugins folder by both ftp and phpMyAdmin to make sure the mylivechatplugin or any other plugins are not the cause of the problem.

In the `wp-posts` table, I also deleted all the items with 'revision' as the post_type.

Finally I checked to ensure the credentials are written correctly in wp_config.

I switched to a different theme and i could then access the posts but still couldn't edit them in the /wp-admin posts menu. So this could be a theme specific issue but probably not.

Comment: can you create a new post and then see/edit it? in other words is this effecting all posts or just old posts?

Comment: Looks like the sit was hacked again. there's dirty javascript in the header. And no I cannot do that.

Comment: you should really look into [wordfence](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/). It is security for Wordpress sites, it works great, has good support, and can be setup to send email reports when users login, or an attacker is trying to login using wrong username.

Comment: I would also suggest [P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler)](http://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) to make sure all of your plugins are operating correctly. I had a site totally unresponsive and spend days trying to fix my server and my custom code only to figure out it was a third party plugin that updated and had bugs in it that just froze my site.